# android file creating on custom location of phone memory neither in internal storage nor external

Tags: android, createfile

I want to know that in Android, is it possible to create a file inside the custom location folder like "**/storage/emulated/0/my_folder/my_file.txt**"?

I can create the file, but it was inside my application internal memory like
"**/data/data/package-name**".........but I want to store my file inside phone memory as shown above and I want to access it for later use like using camera taking a picture and saving that its own directory.....

each time I search I get creating a file on internal memory(ie, /data/data/) or writing on the external memory card(sd card).....but I want to create files on my own custom location as seen above...

is it possible? if it is then how I coded it? which method is used for setting that path I wanted and how set the `fileoutputstream` to write that file into that location? I couldn't find that such function... pls help...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please read below link and it will make you satisfy for all conditions.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java

Comment: sorry sir....could you pointing me which portion i want to read to get it all done...i couldnt find any right solution in that page...thanks for your response